# How to set a subfolder as webapp root on Azure Linux

Tags: linux, azure, es6-modules, azure-linux

I'm using Linux on Azure to host my webapp and it deploys fine. My local dev tree structure looks like this:

- build
- node_modules
- src
  .deployment
  .env
  .gitignore
  package.json
  README.json
  ...

When I deploy to Azure it looks like this:

- dist
- node_modules

Within one of my files I re-utilize some components from a node module like so:

```
import Password from '../../../node_modules/path/to/components/forms/field-types/Password';
```

There are 2 potential ways to make this work:

1. Deploy /dist into the root and have node_modules as a sibling but this then makes the relative path above break and ES6 doesn't allow dynamic import strings nor for them to be within blocks
2. Set the /dist folder as the application root which is actually correct (eg: it contains server.js) and then the relative paths would be correct

I'd prefer #2 however the capability for doing virtual path mapping in Azure doesn't seem to exist so it seems I'd need to leverage `.htaccess`. I'm curious if there are any other ways to do this and also if the root is set to /dist will the relative path still work or will it be blocked by the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**.htaccess** file setting `**RewriteEngine On**` on the request path. So if you add an admin-specific **.htaccess** file in the "subfolder" subfolder, this will preempt the **www** one and circumvent this problem.

EX:

`RedirectMatch ^/my_folder/(.+)/card.jpg$ /script_folder/image.php?perameter=$1`

This willredirect **/my_folder/xyz/card.jpg** to **/script_folder/image.php?perameter=xyz** changing the address bar from typed url to a new url. If you want the browser to stay on the typed url, you can use the following mod rewrite based solution :

```
RewriteEngine on
```

`RewriteRule ^my_folder/(.+)/card.jpg$ /script_folder/image.php?perameter=$1 [L]`

Please refer this DOC:

[Deploy files to App Service - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli)